# Modify a makefile list to Insert quotes

Tags: shell, makefile, quotes

In my makefile, I want to change a list of search directories from...

```
DIRS := ../project ../project/include ../project/src
```

to something like the following...

```
INCLUDES := -I"../project" -I"../project/include" -I"../project/src"
```

I tried using the following command in my makefile...

```
INCLUDES := $(patsubst %,-I"%",$(DIRS))
```

When the makefile outputs the list, it does not include the quotes...

```
INCLUDES = -I../project -I../project/include -I../project/src
```

But, when the compiler is called, the makefile uses the following line...

```
g++ ... -I"../project" -I"../project/include" -I"../project/src"
```

I don't get it. Why are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. It is the shell invoked by the Makefile recipe that makes the quotes disappear. Consider the Makefile:

```
DIRS     := ../project ../project/include ../project/src
INCLUDES := $(patsubst %,-I"%",$(DIRS))

$(info $(INCLUDES))

all:
        @echo $(INCLUDES)
```

`make all` returns:

```
-I"../project" -I"../project/include" -I"../project/src"
-I../project -I../project/include -I../project/src
```

As you see, the `patsubst` text function performs its job nicely.
The quotes are gone because of the variable expansion by the shell.
To preserve those, you should try escaping them:

```
INCLUDES := $(patsubst %,-I\"%\",$(DIRS))
```

In this case, `make all` outputs:

```
-I\"../project\" -I\"../project/include\" -I\"../project/src\"
-I"../project" -I"../project/include" -I"../project/src"
```